# using exec() in openvbx

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to build in applet in OpenVBX that adds an API call to a Desk (formerly known as assistly).

Due to Oauth authentication, I've generally been using twurl to accomplish this - and in php, I've been using exec() to make the API call.  However, when run in an actual flow, it seems that twiml.php won't allow the use of exec(), or even backticks (shell_exec())

Any ideas on how I can workaround that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason exec() doesn't work is PHP's safe_mode being turned on. From elsewhere you've posted, I understand that's not the case.

The next most common reason is that exec (or libexec specifically) is disabled specifically.

After that, you start running into execution issues themselves. The command line/shell  environment will have a different php.ini than the Apache environment so your includes, PATH, etc could be different between the two.

Are you getting any specific errors you can share in your PHP error_log?

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful in diagnosing the issue.  The issue resided in apache not having permissions to exec the shell command